# Back to top button not working on page change

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-mobile, scrolltop

I have some pages created with jquery mobile. I wanted to put a "back to top"-element on them. It works well so far. But when I go to another "page" - for example #sport - (after having scrolled down and used the "TOP!"-Link) and then back to #restaurants, the element does not appear. When I refresh the page, the Link appears and works. Perhaps it is because of the ajax and that the "pages" are in one html? I'm quite new to all that, so I just don't see what's wrong.

my html:

```
<div id="restaurants" class="page page-3" data-role="page">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="title">Restaurants</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content" **id="top"**>
        <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="info-paragraph">
                <h2>Test 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info-paragraph">
                <h2>Test 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info-paragraph">
                <h2>Test 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </div>
                **<a class="top" data-ajax="false" href="#top">TOP!</a>**
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="sport" class="page page-4" data-role="page">
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="title">Sport</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="info-paragraph">
                <h2>Sport 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info-paragraph">
                <h2>Sport 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="info-paragraph">
                <h2>Sport 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
            </div>              
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.top {
    position: fixed;
}
```

My JS:

```
$(document).delegate('a.top', 'click', function () {
$(window).scroll(function(){
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
  $('a.top').fadeIn();
} else {
  $('a.top').fadeOut();
}
});
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, 800);
return false;
});
```

What can I do, that my "Go to top" Element will always appear and not only if I refresh the page?

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer based on JQM 1.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of listening to `scroll` event, use jQM special events `scrollstart` or `scrollstop`. Also, you shouldn't use `.ready()` or anonymous functions `$(function()`, use *page events* instead.

Add `click` listener to `top` anchor once page is created `pagecreate`, and listen to `scrollstop` event to either show or hide the anchor.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#restaurants", function () {
    $('.top').fadeOut("fast");

    $(".top").on("click", function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });

    $(window).on("scrollstop", function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
            $('.top').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.top').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7AvB8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Your scroll function is true even when the link has not been clicked, so it should be moved out of the action handler :

```
$(function (){
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('a.top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('a.top').fadeOut();
    }
});
$(document).delegate('a.top', 'click', function () {

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, 800);
    return false;
});
});
```

So now any scrolling will hide or show the Top link based on the scroll bar position, whether it is in that position from loading, user scrolling, or clicking the Top link.

http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/Nf55S/1/

Comment: Okay, without the fadeIn/fadeOut thing it works perfectly, but sometimes when I refresh the page the link appears and sometimes not. Sometimes it appears, then fades out and I can't see it anymore. That's confusing.

Comment: It fades out if the page is already at the top. Just drop the whole fadein fadeout function block if you want the link always visible

Comment: And notice the additional css i added to position the link

Comment: Yes, thanks!! But I want it to fade in if the user is scrolling :) Why isn't that working?

Comment: If you want it to fade in, it has to also fade out. Right now it's set to fade out once the scroll bar is 150 pixels from the top or less and fade in when its > 150px. Does my fiddle work but your real test not? or are they both not meeting your specification?

Comment: Yes, yes I understand that-that's what I wanted to achieve: fade in and fade out. It worked with my first solution, but there I had the problem with disappearing at page change... In your fiddle it works (except that on refresh it disappears but appears again during scrolling), but on my test page it isn't working with the fading. Really weird, cause sometimes it appears and sometimes not (on refresh).

Comment: Is your JavaScript wrapped in a document ready block? Updating my answer

Comment: No it isn't. Should it be?

Comment: Yes, because the function references the `.top` element, which may not be loaded yet when the function runs.

Comment: Makes sense, but not working :( Why did it work in my first try then... It just doesn't fade. Only sometimes at the begging, it fades in and disappears and I can't click it

Comment: I just don't get it why it's not working properly in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 
`$(window).scrollTop()`  instead of  `$(this).scrollTop()`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. As long as I do not click on the "TOP!" button it works. But if I scroll down, click the "TOP!"-button, then go to another page and back to #restaurants, then the button is away.